# Css not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css

Am trying to style a textarea with css but its not rendering correctly, a part of the border doesnt show.
Heres a screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

This is the css code for the textarea

```
#pheedform textarea {
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-left-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid rgba(153,153,153,1);
    border-bottom:thin;
    width:100%;
    padding:4px;
}
```

And this the css code for the box beneath the textarea

```
 .pheed-options {
        background:#EEEEEE;
        border-top:none;
        padding:5px;
        position:relative;
        top:-7px;
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid #666666;
        border-right:1px solid #666666;
    }
    .pheedOptionItem {
        padding:5px;
        border-right:solid 1px #999999;
    }
```

And this the html

```
<div class="textarea_fix">
                <textarea name="pheed" cols="50" id="pheed">
                </textarea>
                 <div class="pheed-options">
                       <span class="pheedOptionItem">
                       <a href="#" class="pheedAdd_photo">Add Photo</a>
                       </span>
                       <span class="pheedOptionItem"class="pheedOptionItem">
                       <a href="#" class="pheedPostToTwitter">Post to Twitter</a>
                       </span>
                       <span class="pheedOptionItem">
                       <a href="#" class="pheedPostToFacebook">Post to Facebook</a>
                       </span>
                       <span>
                       <a href="#" class="pheedBtn">Pheed</a>
                       </span>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: paste your code to jsfiddle plz (:

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d56fY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set both elements padding the same, either change `#pheedform textarea`s padding to `5px` or `.pheed-options` to `4px`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting width:100% is the cause, because the following scenario occurs: 100% + 1px border-left and 1px border-right.

Either remove the width attribute altogether (just relying on display: block) or give it a fixed, static value.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your screenshot and the jsfiddle, it looks like the `.feed-options` element is a pixel or two wider than the textarea, and is likely being cutoff by having a width wider than its parent, and a parent element having `overflow: hidden`.

I adjusted the padding on `.feed-options` from `padding: 5px` to `padding: 4px` and it lined it up in the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/d56fY/5/

This may prevent it from overflowing the parent element. If not, either adjust the widths to be less than 100% or continue to adjust the padding/margin/borders until its no longer overflowing the `overflow: hidden` element.